# Why is my Joomla site giving me a PayPal donation button error?

Tags: php, joomla, paypal, joomla2.5

I built a site for a nonprofit, using Joomla 2.5.17, and a template from JoomlaShine.

I'm getting an error on the PayPal donation link (see image): **"PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this problem."**

I'm using PayPal code that was created from my account in the PayPal API/code generator.

I've tried every trick I've found on forums, incl. StackOverflow and PayPal's - nothing is working. It looks like very simple code; and it's been a week of hair-tearing frustration.

My level: Beginner; lousy at coding; please be kind... I'm trying to help a nonprofit.

Page where code exists: http://sledfund.org/index.php/modal-width-600-height-400-donate-to-sled-modal

Code I'm using:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 
target="paypal">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden"   name="hosted_button_id" value="PMJUGLKQWEXPJ" />
<input type="image" name="submit" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" 
alt="" width="1"  height="1" border="0" />
</form>
```

Comment: Are you still having issues with this? The code on the website does not match this button, but is working. This error will happen if the button has been deleted from the PayPal account, however.

Answer (score 0):

We also had an issue with a donate module which we were embedding in some articles. I assume that because you have the donate button in an article that it is actually a module and you are using `{loadposition xxx}` to embed it. Open the article in the Article Manager above above `loadposition`, add the following:

```
{emailcloak=off}
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your specific problem but worth giving it a try.